# how can I get the value of a input field using PHP if there are two forms on the page both of POST method

Tags: php, html, forms

I want to get the value of an `<input>` field using PHP.
There are two forms on my page both of POST method.

```html
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="first">
  <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>

<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="second">
  <input type="submit" name="submit1" value="Post">
</form>
```

How do I get the value of the second input field? Even though if I use `$_POST['second']` it shows me an error:

> Undefined index: 'second'

Comment: what is the need of two form ?

Comment: In case if I want then what to do ??

Comment: You can only submit one form at at time - if you split them up, you can only access the data contained in the submitted form

Comment: I think you need to contain both field in on form.

Comment: It seams you are submitting only the first form. How do you submit?

Comment: sorry..I forgot to add a submit button..

Comment: Why would you want when any workaround would only have disadvantages? It's not part of the specs. Each form handles its own elements.

Comment: This is very likely an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What do you actually try to achieve? Why do you think you would need two forms?

Answer (score 0):

The W3C specs define that an input can be associated to only one form. It is a sign of bad design when you need to have multiple forms and the backend has to know which data is present in other forms.

The `<form>` element can contain arbitrary element structures like tables, it can even contain the entire document body content. You should hardly need multiple forms.

A common use-case is to have multiple submit buttons having the same name instead. Only the pressed button will be part of the form data.

```html
<form method="post">
  <input type="text" name="text_input">

  <button type="submit" name="action" value="add">submit</button>
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="update">submit</button>
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="delete">submit</button>
</form>
```

Again, do not do that, however, if you really want to share a field across multiple forms for some reason, this can only be done by javascript intercepting the form submit event. This will not work when scripts are disabled by the user.

```js
document.querySelectorAll('form').forEach(e => {
  e.addEventListener('submit', function() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.multi-form-input').forEach(e => e.setAttribute('form', this.id));
  })
})
```

```html
<input class="multi-form-input" name="common_input" type="text">

<form id="form-1" method="post">
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="1">submit</button>
</form>

<form id="form-2" method="post">
  <button type="submit" name="action" value="2">submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The JavaScript you would place in the `DOMContentLoaded` event listener or at the end of body.